# How to move a path object in Sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app

I use Sketch 3 but why does it not allow me to move the created path object to another location by dragging and dropping it? I can grab any objects such as oval or rectangle but I cannot grab objects created using path in the first place.

Why does it not allow me to grab it and move it to another location? I'm pretty frustrated to use the position and size in the inspector to just change the position of the path object.

Comment: It just won't budge? The only thing that comes to mind is that it is in the edit state.

Comment: Then I even don't know how I can end the edit state - pushing `Esc` just terminates the edit mode, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, <kbd>Esc</kbd> will get you out of edit mode.

There are few things you can do to movie paths easily:

- **1.** One way to make sure that the path is going to move, is to first make sure you have nothing selected. Then you hover over the path so that it turns blue and then you click and drag. This is by no means the easiest method, so I'd recommend method #2.
- **2.** Another way would be to select the path(s) and use <kbd>Alt+[Arrow keys]</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt+Shift+[Arrow keys]</kbd> to move them around.
- **3.** Third method would be to give the path a fill and now you can drag the path from the filled areas. You could even add a fill temporarily and remove the fill when you are done moving the path(s). It should make things way easier in a lot of situations, but not in every single one, like a single straight line for example.

Method #2 is probably the most reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that selecting the path is really, really, really tough in Sketch and requires the huge concentration, but the #1 solution worked.